# Why does "CTYPE" appear in my HTML when I refresh the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Harp and Boostrap. Everytime I refresh the page I have, this is added inside body tags: `"CTYPE html>"`.

Why?

Comment: because `<DO` is probably being mistaken for something else, a plugin maybe?

Comment: I apologize for posting a question like this and I appreciate corrections. Thanks to everybody ;)

Comment: So what was causing it?

Comment: The problem was that `<!DOCTYPE>` was incomplete because of one mistake of mine. So eveytime browser printed it incompleted.

Comment: So it's manually typed? Oh okay, it sounded like it was happening because of something dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is incomplete `"CTYPE html>"`

it has to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

**Definition and Usage**
The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the  tag.

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In HTML 4.01, the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML 4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

HTML5 is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference to a DTD.

Tip: Always add the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration to your HTML documents, so that the browser knows what type of document to expect.

[see DOCTYPE declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

to fix this, check the error in the library or in your file

Comment: T.T Fixed. I feel so noob right now... Thanks a lot